# How to imitate request.user with legacy database in Django?

Tags: mysql, django, database, authentication, legacy

I have to make a simple login functionality with Django working with legacy database where the password is not encrypted. So I am using `Table.objects.filter(login=username,password=password).exists()` to figure out if that particular username password combo exists in a table.

After logging in, I want to use something like `request.user` so that I can use that to access other information related to the user who just logged in to the system.

Is there any way that I can carry a variable across different pages in the system like `request.user`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a [custom authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend). With that, you can use your existing table, and have all the benefits of the standard Django user model.

However I would urge you very strongly to try and move your user data to have properly hashed passwords. In your case, for example, you could run a data migration to copy the data to a new table and hash the passwords on the way.

Comment: I cannot hash the passwords as an already existing system authenticates against that database. Also, I have one table for clients, three tables for retailers and one for admins. Will I be able to create a custom authentication backend that works for all of those or do I have to create separate backends?

Comment: Your backend can do whatever you want; all it has to do is accept a username and password, and return a user.